# print out from switch statement java

Tags: java

here is a piece of code:

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        CLI.parse (args, new String[0]);

        InputStream inputStream = args.length == 0 ?
                System.in : new java.io.FileInputStream(CLI.infile);
        ANTLRInputStream antlrIOS = new ANTLRInputStream(inputStream);

        if (CLI.target == CLI.SCAN || CLI.target == CLI.DEFAULT)
        {
            DecafScanner lexer = new DecafScanner(antlrIOS);
            Token token;
            boolean done = false;
            while (!done)
            {
                try
                {
                    for (token=lexer.nextToken();
                        token.getType()!=Token.EOF; token=lexer.nextToken())
                    {
                        String type = "";
                        String text = token.getText();


                        switch (token.getType())
                        {
                        case DecafScanner.ID:
                          type = " CHARLITERAL";
                          break;

                        }
                        System.out.println (token.getLine() + type + " " + text);
                    }
                    done = true;
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    // print the error:
                    System.out.println(CLI.infile+" "+e);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (CLI.target == CLI.PARSE)
        {
            DecafScanner lexer = new DecafScanner(antlrIOS);
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            DecafParser parser = new DecafParser (tokens);
            parser.program();
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        // print the error:
        System.out.println(CLI.infile+" "+e);
    }
}
}
```

It prints out as it is but somehow it does not print the type out only the default value of it which is an empty string. How can I make it to print out from the switch statement?

Thanks!

Comment: may be put a print statement inside your `case`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging so you can see what the token's type is?

Comment: I was thinking of converting the whole thing into string and print out the case but i am not too sure that this is the best way. not to mention later i need to create more cases

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` to build your string based on the cases you might have, and then print out the string once it's done. You need to make sure you have all possible cases covered and/or provide a `default` block to give you something meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try debugging.
2. Try printing the value from within the switch section, to see if you ever get into it.
3. Try replacing the switch with a simple "==" to see if you ever get "token.getType() == DecafScanner.ID"
4. General suggestion - move the definition of "type" and "next" outside the loop to avoid recreating them again and again.